# Javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Tags: javascript

Here is my FULL code

```
function onValueChange(res) {
    If (res) {

    } 
    else {

    }
};
```

I got error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

on `If (res) {`

What is wrong?

Comment: i in If has to be small.

Comment: Who is DOWN and downvoting?

Comment: case matters in JavaScript :)

Comment: Why when error on token but not on case matters?

Comment: Because `If(...)` is valid syntax, it's a function call. The following token is invalid though.

Comment: But it not `If(...)` it with space `If (...)`

Comment: Spaces between tokens don't have any significance (same as in most other languages).

Comment: Try do this with VBSCRIPT

Comment: It didn't say *all* languages. Of course there are some where they are important (e.g. Python), but I'd argue that in most of them they are not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 updates required in your code

1. Update i in If to lowercase.
2. To end function you need to add closing bracket } Also, there is no need for semicolon at the end of function.

   ```
   function onValueChange(res) {
       if (res) {

       } 
       else {

       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes! I dont know that function is Case sensivity

Comment: Also, there is no need for semicolon at the end of function. Simply end the function with closing bracket }

Comment: No ways. I do not like the idea of down vote. Though I have up voted for you now :) but unfortunately someone again down voted for your question. But i think you should only be concerned for that if you are answering not questioning as question can be anything :)

Comment: @DmitrijHolkin asking others if they have down voted or assuming that someone specific down voted is not well received here. Please don't do that. Move on.

Answer (score 2):

You can't end functions in javascript like that.

Instead of

```
end function
```

you have to use

```
}
```

And `if` has to be lowercase.

Full code:

```
function onValueChange(res) {
    // lowercase if
    if (res) {

    } 
    else {

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it my fall it not End function it is };

Comment: `if` has to be in lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

1. if condition will be lowercase like if not If.
2. ';' mark is not need but it is not responsible for error.

---

```
function onValueChange(res) 
{
if (res){

 }
else {

 }
}
```

Comment: How is that different from the other answers?

Comment: ';' mark is not need but it is not responsible for error.

Comment: Not much different from "Also, there is no need for semicolon at the end of function.". Please don't create noise by posting the same as existing answers.